# You need to add a reference to Mono.Android.Export.Dll when you use ExportAttribute or ExportFieldAttribute

Tags: xamarin

My code works fine, but when I added fragments with a new namespace to the project, I began getting the error

> You need to add a reference to Mono.Android.Export.Dll when you use ExportAttribute or ExportFieldAttribute

I've searched online and found several mentions of unlinking assemblies, but I've also read that this will cause additional errors.

Does anyone know how to solve this bug?

Answer (score 135, accepted):

I found the answer.  Right click **references** and search **Export**.  Just add the **Mono.Android.Export** to your project.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer why it is needed and what it does though.

Comment: Just for clarification, it is called the "Mono.Android.Export" DLL.

Comment: For more clarification, after you right-click References, click Add Reference. The search bar is in the upper right of the form. See @Arun's answer for a screenshot.

Answer (score 51):

[image]
I added reference like @Jeremy Said, it's working

Comment: in my Visual Studio 2017, I am targeting MonoAndroid 5.0, and I see only one Mono.Android.Export.dll, that is from 7.1. Can I find older versions of Mono.Android.Export.dll anywhere to download?

Comment: @LupuSilviu Usually all dlls are individually avaliable to download. Please try searching for it.

Answer (score 15):

If you're using JetBrains Rider, you can solve the issue by adding the `Mono.Android.Export` reference to your Android `.csproj` file:

```xml
<!-- ExampleApp.Android.csproj -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    ...
    <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Mono.Android" />
        <Reference Include="Mono.Android.Export" />
    </ItemGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need download dll from the web if you cant find it in the reference manager

just do following steps:

1. Set the target framework to Android 4.4 kit kat
2. Add reference mono.android.expert.dll
3. set targetFramework as  last good target framework

Clean solution and rebuild

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using VS 2022 (like @Siddhant maurya):

- Right click the "References" folder of the project that gets the error.
- Choose "Add project reference".
- In the "All" tab select "Mono.Android.Export".
- Press "Select".
- (optional) Close VS 2022 and open explorer(Windows) or finder(MacOS) to remove for every project in the solution the "bin" and "obj" folders.
- (optional reopen VS 2022) Rebuild the solution.